# Is it possible to call krun on the configurations output by krun?

Tags: kframework

I'd like K to generate a bunch of configurations which I can then process externally. But then, I may want resume the computation by calling K on each configuration. Is this possible?

I tried looking at the `krun --help` options, but I don't think I saw what I needed. The closest was term parsing, but I'd like to pass it full configurations rather than just a term.

Alternatively, is there API for K to use with OCaml?
e.g. if I have an already compiled K semantics, is there any API to call K on a file, gain access to the AST, and run K over them?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is the following:

```
krun $args --output kast --output-file output.kast
krun --term --parser cat output.kast
```

Comment: krun needs its input to be in an AST format it understands in order to pass to the backend for execution. In this case, due to `--output kast`, this is already the case. Thus `--parser cat` is telling krun to take output.kast, cat it, and treat the result on stdout as the parsed input configuration to krun

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when `krun` returns multiple configurations? I see it builds a tree of `#Or` nodes, but when passing this to `krun`, I get an error: `[Error] Internal: Uncaught exception thrown of type ClassCastException.` I suppose `krun` isn't able to start from multiple starting configurations.

Comment: What backend are you using? I wouldn't expect this to work on any backend other than the Haskell backend, but if you are using the haskell backend, feel free to create a GitHub issue for this crash.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm using the Java backend. It works for individual configurations it seems, but not for the kast including multiple paths.